# Why does Sling/Jackrabbit use twice the disc space to store a file?

Tags: jackrabbit, sling

**Why does Sling/Jackrabbit use twice the disc space to store a file and what can I do to prevent it from doing this?**

I'm working on a project where we're storing files and associated data in Sling. For operational reasons we would like to avoid excessive disc usage. We've hit a problem where anytime we store a file in Sling the amount of disc space used appears to be double.

For instance, I have 47 megs of files. When uploaded to Sling I have 53 megs in the datastore, there's a lot of different files so I can accept that amount of inflation. However if we look at the total size of the Jackrabbit repository we see a different story ...

```
jackrabbit]# du -s
118688  .
jackrabbit]# du -s repository/datastore/
53296   repository/datastore/
jackrabbit]# du -s workspaces/default/blobs/
53464   workspaces/default/blobs/
```

Now the data associated with these files is quite small (<1 meg) so I don't see why the workspace is storing so much data when it's supposed to be all stored in the datastore. This problem gets worse when I upload a larger file, here I've added a 277 meg file to the above repository.

```
jackrabbit]# du -s
686508  .
jackrabbit]# du -s repository/datastore/
337152  repository/datastore/
jackrabbit]# du -s workspaces/default/blobs/
337320  workspaces/default/blobs/
```

I've uploaded sets of multi gigabyte files and this behaviour seems to be consistent.

I'm using the default repository.xml file created by the Sling standalone 6 when its run, this does appear to have the FileDataStore configured (see below). I was under the impression that with the FileDataStore configured Jackrabbit wouldn't store its files in blobs but that appears to be the case here. Can anyone provide me with a reason why this behaviour is exibited or a way to disable it? It seems exceedingly strange that a system would essentially store a file twice.

```
<Repository>
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository"/>
    </FileSystem>

    <DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore"/>

    <Security appName="Jackrabbit">
        <SecurityManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.DefaultSecurityManager" workspaceName="security">
    </SecurityManager>

        <AccessManager class="org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server.impl.security.PluggableDefaultAccessManager">
        </AccessManager>

        <LoginModule class="org.apache.sling.jcr.jackrabbit.server.impl.security.PluggableDefaultLoginModule">
            <param name="anonymousId" value="anonymous"/>
            <param name="adminId" value="admin"/>
        </LoginModule>
    </Security>

    <Workspaces rootPath="${rep.home}/workspaces" defaultWorkspace="default"/>

    <Workspace name="${wsp.name}">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
        </FileSystem>
        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.db.DerbyPersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${wsp.home}/db;create=true"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
            <param name="shutdownOnClose" value="false"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
        <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
            <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
            <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
        </SearchIndex>
    </Workspace>

    <Versioning rootPath="${rep.home}/version">
        <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
            <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/version" />
        </FileSystem>

        <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.db.DerbyPersistenceManager">
            <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${rep.home}/version/db;create=true"/>
            <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_"/>
            <param name="shutdownOnClose" value="false"/>
        </PersistenceManager>
    </Versioning>

    <SearchIndex class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.SearchIndex">
        <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/index"/>
        <param name="supportHighlighting" value="true"/>
    </SearchIndex>
</Repository>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this with the current Sling trunk, running the launchpad/builder jar, I mount http://localhost:8888 via WebDAV and add 3 files in the repository under /tmp: files a and b which are two copies of the same 141MB file (to verify that the datastore stores only one copy), and file c which is 281MB. I then get 422MB under repository/datastore and 4.5MB under workspaces, as expected. The Sling 6 release is quite old, you might want to compare with trunk (and yes we need a newer full Sling release).

Comment: I think you are either using a very old version of Jackrabbit, or a very old (persistence manager) configuration. Specially, you should use a [bundle persistence manager](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ#Bundle_Database_PM), those are much faster and use less disk space.